# Compare values within the single variable

Tags: correlation, nonparametric

I have a 5 categories of the occupations — starting from jobs with low physical effort like an IT guy, to the labor-intensive occupations like coal-mining etc. The categories are numbered from 1 to 5. The higher number — the greater physical effort.

With every category comes value (score) e.g.:

```
1 —> 65
2 —> 70 
3 —> 80 
etc.
```

What I want to do is to find some statistical test which can be used to tell me if there's statistically significant tendency that that when the occupation are more labor-intensive, the score is getting higher (or lower).

I was thinking about using a simple correlation or maybe some non-parametric tests (chi-squared?), but I'm a bit of a statistical newbie, so I don't wanna make a mistake with the choice of the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your metric which measures physical effort ascribe ranks to different occupations, and since the number of ranks is quite small, what does not allow us to assume continuity of this measure, the best fitting statistical test would Spearman's rank correlation test.